# Change The Default Value of Boolean

Tags: c#, boolean, default

I'm writing an application, where I have quite a lot Properties of Type Boolean  defined:

```
    private bool kajmak = true;
    public bool Kajmak
    {
        get { return kajmak ; }
        set { kajmak = value; FirePropertyChanged(() => Kajmak); }
    }
```

As you see, I set `kajmak` to `true` at the beginning..-the reason is nonrelevant-. (You might know that the **default** value of a bool variable is **false**).

Now, is there a way, to change the default value of a `bool` to `true`? So I would write:

```
private bool kajmak; //kajmak = true
```

instead of

```
private bool kajmak = true;
```

What could I do to achieve this?

Comment: I don't believe you can change this. Just keep doing what you're doing.

Comment: Don't do it, it's more trouble than it's worth, don't even think about doing it.

Comment: Even if you could ... what would you gain?

Comment: Curious why this was downvoted. Admittedly, it's a bad practice to want to do this, but the question itself was fine.

Comment: See my answer around the new C Sharp 6.0 way to do this

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Because booleans are false by default, I use positive forms in my names, like `IsInitialized`, `HasSomething` etc. which I want to be false by default until I explicitly set them.

If you find you need something to be true by default, maybe you need to rename your variable so it makes more sense when the default is false.

Comment: I've always done this as well, and then I realized it's kind of  a silly argument  when I came across a scenario where I want the positive form to be true by default. That basically reverses this argument :)

Comment: Well, you can always set them to true in your constructor. :)

Answer (score 80):

C Sharp 6.0 has introduced a nice new way to do this:

```
 public bool YourBool { get; set; } = true;
```

This is equivalent to the old way of:

```
    private bool _yourBool = true;

    public bool YourBool 
    {
        get { return _yourBool; }
        set { _yourBool = value; }
    }
```

see this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2014/11/20/new-features-in-c-6.aspx

Answer (score 12):

In service:

```
public bool Kajmak { get; set; } = true;
```

Answer (score 4):

No. There's no way to change the default value assigned by .NET. Your best bet is to either assign the appropriate default in the private member:

```
private book kajmak = false;
```

Or use the Constructor like you're supposed to and assign the class defaults there:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass()
    {
        Kajmak = false;
    }

    public book Kajmak { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no possibility to change the default value. If you could change the default-value, it wouldn't be the default anymore ;).

But to set the default-value to null, you could use this:

```
bool? kajmak;
```

But that's not what you want...

Answer (score 0):

In the process of trying to do something similar, a colleague enlightened me to the bool? type. It can be true, false, or null, and does not object to being on the left side of such a comparator. This does not answer your question of how to default bool to true, but does solve your conceptual problem of wanting your variables to be definable as true by default.

I only post because this was the top result when I searched, and this information was helpful to me. Hopefully it will be to others who find this page.

Answer (score -2):

You may create a class myBool that defaults to false and an implicit conversion from bool to your class.

Comment: Too much overhead, dont do this